# Parameter Direction Output SYS_REFCURSOR in ODBC

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

How I'll declare the type of SYS_REFCURSOR in ODBC parameter type?

Here's my code:

```
   OdbcParameterCollection oParam = new OdbcCommand().Parameters;
   oParam.Add("Username ", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "Aries";
   oParam.Add("PASSWORD ", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "1234";
   oParam.Add("RESULT", OdbcType.??).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; //Problem here
   _dt = this.Execute("{ CALL spValidateLogin(?, ?, ?) }", oParam);
```

Comment: What if you don't pass parameter type? Create parameter with only a name and direction. And then, using this type of connectivity for Oracle is not preferable. You should use ODP.Net for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is - you've selected wrong connectivity for Oracle. You may be just limited to Text execution with odbcCommand because I don't see OdbcType having any of that.

OleDb will be discontinued and it is not advisable to use. So, you have MS Data Provider for Oracle

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08.aspx

But even Microsoft recommends using vendor-provided data connectivity for .NET. In which case you need to install ODP.NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx